# Using Knockout mapping with Knockout ValidatedObservable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I'm struggling with how to update my bound viewmodel from an ajax call whilst using a `validatedObservable`.

Previously I get the initial data from an ajax call and intially bound like this:

```
self.quote = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quoteMapping);

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

and when a user changed something in the 'quote', I'd make another ajax call passing the changes and the return from the ajax call would be the complete 'quote' (and I *do* need to bring the whole 'quote', as a change to one item on the quote can server-side affect other items and also other properties in the top level which therefore need to be updated in the client-side view model) which I would update the bound view model with (using the other signature of fromJS), thusly:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quote);
```

However, now I want the view model to be a `validatedObservable`.  For the inital load this is pretty straightforward:

```
self.quote = ko.validatedObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quoteMapping));

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

but I'm stuck on how to update the view model with a validated observable

I can't use **ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quote);** because that will update self.quote with a plain observable not a validated observable and unsurpisingly that doesn't work.

Here are a couple of *very simplified* fiddles to illustrate the problem.

Plain Observable (which works):
https://jsfiddle.net/stevedavey/1tup0agt/

Validated Observable (which doesn't):
https://jsfiddle.net/stevedavey/yh233wht/

I'd appreciate any clue as to what I need to do to be able to get an amended 'quote' from an ajax call and update my validated observable using ko mapping.

I suspect I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use `ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quote);` because that will update self.quote with a plain observable not a validated observable and unsurpisingly that doesn't work.

You can use `ko.mapping.fromJS`, you're just doing it wrong. Take the time to read [the documentation of the mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) - it's only one page and not even a long one.

You can define additional behavior by passing an options object. In this case you want to [customize object creation using `create`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create) - like returning a validated observable.

I'm citing the documentation example with one change:

```
var mapping = {
    'children': {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.validatedObservable(options.data);
        }
    }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Of course you can use `create` at the root level of the mapping options, too, but the mapping plugin also allows you to be more specific.

Side note: Try to re-use the same function to initialize and to update your viewmodel. There is no real reason to keep two different pieces of code around that update the same observable.

Comment: I knew I was doing it wrong! :D  I just needed a a nudge in the right direction (not nerd-snarkiness at missing the obvious).  The **create** functions in my mapping defnition (the **self.QuoteMapping** in `ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quoteMapping)` - see the code in my question) return observables, so that's what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This was meant as a nudge. ;) A pure snarky answer would not have contained a pointer into the right direction.

Comment: Well, yes that's true. ;)  I still have one more usage/syntax issue that you could nudge me with!  I can get the `create` on the child objects to return a  validated observable but how do I get the `validatedObservable` from the top level.  I've updated the 'Validated Observable' fiddle with comments ref'ing your SO username indicating what I'm stuck with.  Nudges (even snarky ones! ;> ) appreciated.

Comment: @steve Instead of building the object graph with the mapping plugin, wich becomes tedious quickly, create separate viewmodels that reference each other and let them create themselves with minimal involvement of the mapping plugin. I've rewritten your second fiddle completely. It now features a self-sufficient App -> Quote -> QuoteItem viewmodel hierarchy. See: https://jsfiddle.net/yh233wht/38/. I think that's very close to how you should do it. Also pay attention to the view modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's much tidier and works as far as the add goes but I'm still struggling with how to get validatedObservables out of the mapping.  I want to be able to call for example quote.isValid (maybe I'm misunderstanding but I had the impression that ko validation could handle the 'bubbling up' of validity within an object hierarchy), get the validation errors from quote and thus display them in a validation summary.  I suspect I'm missing something fundamental about ko validation.

Comment: Currently the App's `quote` property is a regular observable. All you need to do is change that during object construction. If during the mapping process the mapping plugin finds an existing observable on the target object then it won't replace that observable itself, but only its contents. Therefore the validatedObservable will stay there once you've set it up that way.

Comment: With Tomolak's help, some tweaking of my own and my boss's help I got the validation working as expected. The two things to be amended were the fact that the return from the init in Quote needed to be wrapped in a validatedObservable and the initializing of the quote property needed to be in the form of `ko.validatedObservable(self.quote);` rather than `self.quote = ko.validatedObservable();`.  I've updated the fiddle to show this: [linl](https://jsfiddle.net/stevedavey/yh233wht/)